# PHP IF != 0 not working

Tags: php

Scenario is as following:
I have a registration form that creates an activation code and assigns it to a text field within the database.

Text Field: user_activation

Code that assigns the activation code.

```
p = new Password();
    $activation = $p->randomBase64String(100); // 100=length of string  
    $activation_code = $config->httpHost."/activation/?user=".$username."&hash=".$activation;
```

Later in the code $activation is assigned to $user_activation

```
new_user->user_activation = $activation;
```

An email is send ti to the user with an activation link, which upon clicking changes that long activation code to a  0 (text value)

```
activate_username =  $sanitizer->text($_GET['user']);
$activate_hash =  $sanitizer->text($_GET['hash']);

if(wire("users")->get($activate_username)->id) {
    if(strcmp(wire("users")->get($activate_username)->user_activation, $activate_hash) == 0 || wire("users")->get($activate_username)->user_activation == 0) {
        echo "Your account has been activated!<br><br>";
        $activate_user = wire("users")->get($activate_username);
        $activate_user->of(false);
        $activate_user->user_activation = "0";
        $activate_user->save();
    }
```

So the user_activation field within each user either as a value of 0 OR a long activation code.

Upon logging in I check this value to determinate whether a user can login OR whether they still need to be activated.

Login code

```
//Check if submit is issued
if($input->post->login_submit) {

/*check for login before outputting markup
if($input->post->user && $input->post->pass) { */

    $user = $sanitizer->username($input->post->user);
    $pass = $input->post->pass; 

    if($user->user_activation != 0) {
    $login_errors .= "Sorry, but you need to activate your account!";
    $out .= $form;
    }


    elseif($session->login($user, $pass)) {
        // login successful
        $session->redirect("/"); 
        }

    else {
        $login_errors .= "Username or Password is incorrect";
        $out .= $form;
    }


}

else {
    $out .= $form;
}
```

The problem is this does not seem to work. Any ideas why this don't work. I have tried the below, none of which worked.

```
if($user->user_activation != 0) 
if($user->user_activation !== 0) 
if($user->user_activation != "0") 
if($user->user_activation !== "0")
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($user->user_activation);` output?

Comment: You can't say that the comparision is not working if you do not the actual value that $user->user_activation is returning.

Comment: It seems to me like `$user` is not an actual object, so wouldn't have the `user_activation` value; like @AmalMurali suggested, if you show us a var dump (maybe of `$user`) it could help.

Comment: Wait, where is the information stored? From the code examples it looks like you are setting `$user->user_activation` on the activation landing page - and that's it. Every new page load (login, for example) does not hold the information unless you save it somehwere and initialize your `$user` class with it next time.

Comment: `var_dump($user->user_activation);` outputs `string(1) "0"`

Comment: When a user is not activated for example it outputs the long activation code: `string(34) "q3458sadfkljsdflkhasfklsdfasdfsadf"`

Comment: Below dumps are when user is logged on, so you guys are probably right. Don't think that field is accessible prior to login. Need to define a way to take provided username and then access the field.